# Doctrine DQL that produces the output of a RIGHT JOIN?

Tags: join, doctrine, doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to return a list of all members, and also include their membership number if they have it.

The models are setup as listed below:
The member class:

```
class Member {
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=255) */
    protected $email = '';
}
```

The membership class:

```
class Membership {

   /** @Id @Column(type="integer") 
    * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
   protected $id;

   /** @OneToOne(targetEntity="Member") */
   protected $member = 0;

   /** @Column(type="integer") */
   protected $membership_number = 0;
}
```

I want to create a query that returns ALL the members, AND also shows a membership number if it exists for that member.

Can't figure out how to do this.

The query below selects all members with a membership, not what I need though. 
Right joins don't work so I'm not sure what to do.

```
$this->_em->createQuery("SELECT m, mb FROM Membership mb JOIN mb.member m");
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943886/sql-doctrine-left-join-problem